# jupyter notebook taking only capital letter as input IN [ ], not taking in[ ]

Tags: jupyter-notebook

jupyter notebook taking only capital letters as input IN[], but not as in[]

I have tried youtube searching but nothing worked

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just check for any extra font sytle added in system , reset the system (pc) font